# TTY key codes changed in "bind -x" bash callback

Tags: c, bash, readline, tty

I'm trying to bind an interactive program to a key in bash using `bind -x`. This program sets the terminal in raw mode during its execution, and resets the previous settings at exit.

Some keys have different codes when the program is run via the bash binding. For example, the down arrow code is `<Esc>OB` instead of `<Esc>[B`. I'm trying to understand why and find a solution to have the "normal" codes.

I printed the flags obtained with `tcgetattr`, they are the same whether the program is run normally or via the binding.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the terminal is set in appcursor mode.

To unset it, write `"\x1B[?1l"` to the tty.